# nginx ドメイン名でアクセスできない

Tags: centos, nginx

nginx初心者です。

レンタルVPSでWebサイトを公開しようと、CentOS7上でnginx1.12.1を動かしているのですが、ドメイン名でアクセスすると「応答時間が長すぎます」とエラーを吐かれ、アクセスできません。
IPアドレスからだとアクセスできます。

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`は以下のように設定しています。

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ドメイン；

    charset UTF-8;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
}
```

エラーログを参照しましたが、なにもエラーはありませんでした。

ファイヤーウォールなど行った設定は以下の3つです。

- CentOS7のファイヤーウォールを確認firewall-cmd --list-allしましたが、 public
  (active)内に「ports: 80/tcp」があり、80ポートは許可。
  また、ファイヤーウォールをすべて停止しても、アクセスできません。
- zoneではpublic (active)のサービスにhttpを追加
- DNSの設定やネームサーバの設定は、お名前.comにて行い、レンタルVPSの指定通りに設定しました。

インストールしているものは、

- PHP 5.4.16(cli)
- PHP 5.4.16 (fpm-fcgi)
- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19

です。

どのようにしたらドメイン名でのアクセスが可能になるでしょうか？
教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/89939

Comment: ドメインの名前解決は問題なく出来ますか？クライアントのターミナル（Windowsならコマンドプロンプト）で 「ping ドメイン名」と実行して、「ドメイン名が見つかりませんでした」と表示される場合は DNSの設定が必用です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take88さん
ご回答ありがとうございます。設定から反映されるまで最大2日、3日かかる場合があると調べたところ書いてありましたので、返信が遅くなりました。

VPSはconohaを利用しています。
ドメイン設定を見直していたところ、conoha上での設定が怪しいなということに気づき、設定し直したらドメインからのアクセスができました。

ありがとうございました。